# html5 canvas: auto font size for drawn wrapped rotated text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation, word-wrap

suppose that there is a text to be drawn inside a rotated bounding rectangle (not aligned to normal axes x-y), and that **text can be also rotated**, 
given the *max width* of the bounding box, how to select the **best font size** to use to draw a **wrapped text inside** that bounding box in html5 canvas and javascript?

I know that method: **measureText**() can measure dimensions of give font size, but I need the inverse of that: using a known width to get the problem font size.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have to find the font point size to make it fit. The font will smoothly scale up and down according to the current transformation scale.

All you do is `measureText` to find its `textWidth`, get the `pointSize` from the `context.font` attribute then if you have the `width` and `height` of the box you need to fit then find the minimum of the `width / textWidth` and `height / pointSize` and you have the scale that you need to render the font at.

As a function

```
var scale2FitCurrentFont = function(ctx, text, width, height){
    var points, fontWidth;
    points = Number(ctx.font.split("px")[0]); // get current point size
    points += points * 0.2; // As point size does not include hanging tails and
                            // other top and bottom extras add 20% to the height
                            // to accommodate the extra bits  
    var fontWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
    // get the max scale that will allow the text to fi the current font
    return Math.min(width / fontWidth, height / points);
}
```

The arguments are

- **ctx** is current context to draw to
- **text** the text to draw
- **width** the width to fit the text to
- **height** the height to fit the text to

Returns the scale to fit the text within the width and height.

The demo has it all integrated and it draws random boxes and fills with random text from your question. It keeps the font selection and point size separate from the font scaling so you can see it will work for any font and any point size.

```js
var demo = function(){
    
    /** fullScreenCanvas.js begin **/
    var canvas = (function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
        if(canvas !== null){
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
        // creates a blank image with 2d context
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); 
        canvas.id = "canv";    
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.top = "0px";
        canvas.style.left = "0px";
        canvas.style.zIndex = 1000;
        canvas.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        return canvas;
    })();
    var ctx = canvas.ctx;
    
    /** fullScreenCanvas.js end **/
    /** FrameUpdate.js begin **/
    var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;
    var cw = w / 2;
    var ch = h / 2;
    
    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2; // 360 to save typing 
    var PIh = Math.PI / 2; // 90 
    
    
    
    // draws a rounded rectangle path
    function roundedRect(ctx,x, y, w, h, r){

        ctx.beginPath(); 
        ctx.arc(x + r, y + r, r, PIh * 2, PIh * 3);  
        ctx.arc(x + w - r, y + r, r, PIh * 3, PI2);
        ctx.arc(x + w - r, y + h - r, r, 0, PIh);  
        ctx.arc(x + r, y + h - r, r, PIh, PIh * 2);  
        ctx.closePath(); 
    }
    
    // random words
    var question = "Suppose that there is a text to be drawn inside a rotated bounding rectangle (not aligned to normal axes x-y), and that text can be also rotated, given the max width of the bounding box, how to select the best font size to use to draw a wrapped text inside that bounding box in html5 canvas and javascript? I know that method: measureText() can measure dimensions of give font size, but I need the inverse of that: using a known width to get the problem font size. thanks.";
    question = question.split(" ");
    var getRandomWords= function(){
        var wordCount, firstWord, s, i, text;
        wordCount = Math.floor(rand(4)+1);
        firstWord = Math.floor(rand(question.length - wordCount));
        text = "";
        s = "";
        for(i = 0; i < wordCount; i++){
            text += s + question[i + firstWord];
            s = " ";  
        }
        return text;
    }
    

    // fonts to use?? Not sure if these are all safe for all OS's
    var fonts = "Arial,Arial Black,Verdanna,Comic Sans MS,Courier New,Lucida Console,Times New Roman".split(",");
    // creates a random font with random points size in pixels
    var setRandomFont = function(ctx){
        var size, font;
        size = Math.floor(rand(10, 40));
        font = fonts[Math.floor(rand(fonts.length))];
        ctx.font = size + "px " + font;
    }
    var scale2FitCurrentFont = function(ctx, text, width, height){
        var points, fontWidth;
        var points = Number(ctx.font.split("px")[0]); // get current point size
        points += points * 0.2;
        var fontWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
        // get the max scale that will allow the text to fi the current font
        return Math.min(width / fontWidth, height / points);
    }


    var rand = function(min, max){
        if(max === undefined){
            max = min;
            min = 0;
        }
        return Math.random() * (max - min)+min;
    }
    var randomBox = function(ctx){
        "use strict";
        var width, height, rot, dist, x, y, xx, yy,cx, cy, text, fontScale;
        // get random box
        width = rand(40, 400);
        height = rand(10, width * 0.4);
        rot = rand(-PIh,PIh);
        dist = Math.sqrt(width * width + height * height)
        x = rand(0, ctx.canvas.width - dist);
        y = rand(0, ctx.canvas.height - dist);
        xx = Math.cos(rot);
        yy = Math.sin(rot);
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        // rotate the box
        ctx.setTransform(xx, yy, -yy, xx, x, y);
        // draw the box
        roundedRect(ctx, 0, 0, width, height, Math.min(width / 3, height / 3));
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        
        // get some random text
        text = getRandomWords();
        // get the scale that will fit the font
        fontScale = scale2FitCurrentFont(ctx, text, width - textMarginLeftRigth * 2, height - textMarginTopBottom * 2);
        // get center of rotated box
        cx = x + width / 2 * xx + height / 2 * -yy;
        cy = y + width / 2 * yy + height / 2 * xx;
        // scale the transform
        xx *= fontScale;
        yy *= fontScale;
        // set the font transformation to fit the box
        ctx.setTransform(xx, yy, -yy, xx, cx, cy);
        // set up the font render
        ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle"
        // draw the text to fit the box
        ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);
    }
    var textMarginLeftRigth = 8; // margin for fitted text in pixels
    var textMarginTopBottom = 4; // margin for fitted text in pixels
    var drawBoxEveryFrame = 60; // frames between drawing new box
    var countDown = 1;
    // update function will try 60fps but setting will slow this down.    
    function update(){
        // restore transform
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
      
        // fade clears the screen 
        ctx.fillStyle = "white"
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1/ (drawBoxEveryFrame * 1.5);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
      
        // reset the alpha
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        
        // count frames
        countDown -= 1;
        if(countDown <= 0){ // if frame count 0 the draw another text box
            countDown = drawBoxEveryFrame;
            setRandomFont(ctx);
            randomBox(ctx);
        }
        
        if(!STOP){ // do until told to stop.
            requestAnimationFrame(update);
        }else{
            STOP = false;
            
        }
    }
    update();
}

// demo code to restart on resize
var STOP = false;  // flag to tell demo app to stop 
function resizeEvent(){
    var waitForStopped = function(){
        if(!STOP){  // wait for stop to return to false
            demo();
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(waitForStopped,200);
    }
    STOP = true;
    setTimeout(waitForStopped,100);
}
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeEvent);
demo();
/** FrameUpdate.js end **/
```

Comment: Nicely efficient! :-)

Comment: thank you Blindman67, your answer is very helpful, I shall try that on my code. thanks a lot